# Is there a way to load a LaunchAgent as another user?

Tags: permission, launchd

From a script run as root I copy a LaunchAgent `.plist` to `/Users/xyz/Library/LaunchAgents`.

If I load that via `launchctl` logged in as user `xyz` it works without problems. If I try to load it from the script with the following command:

```
sudo -u xyz launchctl load /Users/xyz/Library/LaunchAgents/x.y.z.plist
```

it doesn't work. The error message is

```
Could not open job overrides database at /private/var/db/launchd.db/com.apple.launchd.peruser.0/overrides.plist: 13: Permission denied  
launch_msg(): Socket is not connected
```

Is there any other way to accomplish my task?

Comment: Could you move it to `/Library/LaunchAgents/` and add a `UserName` key?

Answer (score 4):

It looks to me like the permissions error is just a symptom of a much deeper problem: you're trying to load the item into the wrong [mach bootstrap context](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SECTION9). Specifically, you're running the launchctl command as xyz, but it's trying to load the item into root's context, which xyz doesn't have permissions to do. What you *want* is to load the item into xyz's context instead (which xyz should have permissions to do).

Ok, let me back up a bit, and give you a bit of a summary of the launchd hierarchy in OS X. When the OS boots, it starts a master instance of launchd (the "system" launchd), which loads items from the various Library/LaunchDaemons folders.

When a user logs in (or otherwise starts a "session"), a new "bootstrap context" is created, a new instance of launchd (the "user" launchd) is started (in that new context) which loads items from the various Library/LaunchAgents folders (all within that new context).

When you use `sudo -u xyz ...`, it switches user IDs to xyz, but doesn't switch to xyz's context.

Now, there are a couple of cases here: first, if xyz isn't logged in (i.e. doesn't have an active session), they don't have a bootstrap context or a launchd instance, so you can't load a LaunchAgent as them. Basically, LaunchAgents load into user sessions, so if there's no session there's nothing to load it into. On the other hand, this shouldn't be a problem: next time xyz logs in, your item will be loaded automatically (as long as it's in the right place).

If xyz *is* logged in, you can get the process ID of some process within their session, and use `launchctl bsexec` to switch to that process's bootstrap context (and then use `sudo -u xyz` to switch UIDs to xyz, and then load the item):

```
loadUser=xyz
loadPID=$(ps -axj | awk "/^$loadUser / {print \$2;exit}")
launchctl bsexec $loadPID sudo -u $loadUser launchctl load /Users/xyz/Library/LaunchAgents/x.y.z.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that you can do this in two steps.

First sudo into `root`

```
sudo -s
```

Then impersonate the user

```
su -l user
```

Apparently that establishes the correct context and `launchctl` works.